# Unexpected character error in C# while copy code from word file in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, text, visual-studio-2019, editor

Unexpected character error in C# while copy code from word file in visual studio 2019

i just copy a code from word file
i use  the same code in other visual studio versions and works fine

the problem i didn't found any errors

i followed some suggestions related to clean project - empty appdata but not worked

the code is very simple like this

```
public class Teacher 
‎{ 
‎    public int TeacherId { get; set; } 
‎    public string Code { get; set; } 
‎    public string Name { get; set; } 
‎} ‎
public class Student 
‎{ 
‎    public int StudentId { get; set; } 
‎    public string Code { get; set; } 
‎    public string Name { get; set; } 
‎    public string EnrollmentNo { get; set; } 
‎}‎
```

[image]

rewring the code manual takes time and also i want to know the reason as i didn't found any related reasons avaiable on my online search

in notepad when encod as ansi it shows like this
[image]

appsetting json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: copy the code itself from this topics show me the same errors so you can try in your visual studio editor

Comment: Would you mind sharing your appsettings.json

Comment: If you copy from word to notepad then copy from notepad to VS, do you get the same issue?

Comment: i update the post 
when copy in notepad as utf still the same but ansi code show strange samples

Comment: There is a character 8206 are the start of each line: https://www.codetable.net/decimal/8206. Is the document a Right-to-Left document? Maybe change the whole document to Left-to-Right

Comment: make it left to right didn't resolve - i have to copy to notepad every time and remove the character manual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ Chris.

According to the description of the error and the actual error code obtained from the online compiler after copy/paste. Your code contains characters that is not visible but that the compiler is trying to interpret. You could try to delete all the spaces in the code and press Enter again (it did work for me),like the code in the picture below:

delete all the spaces in the code:
[image]
press Enter again:

[image]

Comment: the problem also related to microsoft word itself - page encoding - as when i opened word file with other app -the problem was solved